# Could not find information about 'NameError: date'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4, pelican

I am working with pelican static site generator for my blog, I was using correctly, but strangely I found that `.md` articles are not compiling and it throws me these strange errors.

I looked at my article pages, everything is fine, this is my article header

```
Title: some title
slug: some-title
Date: 2016-11-19
Category: code
Tags: python, python
Authors: nix1947(Manoj)
```

I couldn't find, why I am getting this error?

I looked over the  `pelicanconf.py` file, particularly for the date section, everything is ok
here is my date section of my pelicanconf.py file

```
DATE_FORMAT = { 'en': '%d %m %Y'}
DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT = '%d %m %Y'
PDF_GENERATOR = False
REVERSE_CATEGORY_ORDER = True
ARTICLE_URL = '{date:%Y}/{date:%-m}/{date:%-d}/{slug}/'
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = ARTICLE_URL + 'index.html'
```

These are the bunch of errors that pelican throws when I try to compile an article.

```
(nix1947blog)nix1947@nix1947:~/projects/nix1947blog/content/blog$ 
-> Modified: content. re-generating...
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tags.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/categories.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/archives.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/Updating-linux-packages-from-particular-repositories.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/heroku-rails-cheatsheet.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/Data structures and algorithms using python.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/rails-5-cheatsheet.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/authors.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/index.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/Web-scraping-using-python-3.5.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/hello-world.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/installing-latex-in-linux.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/author/nix1947.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/author/nix1947manoj-gautam.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/category/sysadmin.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/category/code.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/category/documentation.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tag/ruby.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tag/linux.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tag/python.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tag/programming.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tag/documentation.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tag/system-admininstration.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tag/rails.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tag/publishing.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tag/blog.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tag/heroku.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
Done: Processed 6 articles, 0 drafts, 0 pages and 0 hidden pages in 0.32 seconds.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.md` files are fine. You're getting errors from `.html` files in your `content`, which looks like the output of a previous `pelican` run:

```
ERROR: Skipping blog/output/tags.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
```

Remove the `blog/output` folder inside your `content` folder and the errors should go away.

Answer (score 0):

To construct URL it is trying to access date field but you have not mentioned date for those URLs and that is the reason for error.

PS :
This should be comment instead of answer but I don't have enough reputation so adding it here.

Comment: where i have to put date for those urls, the urls are generated automatically, based on the tags provided in each article.md file for instance the above article has the python tag, so the python.html url and page is automatically generated, and even, each articles in my source has the date